# center <a> tag text and image vertical in Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap row with some columns. In the columns I've added a span tag with text and an image between <'a'> and <'/a'>. 
I need the text to vertical align with the image, now it's always placed to the top of the column. I tried vertical-align: middle but no luck.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <a href="http://www.xxxx.xxx" target="_blank">
            <span style="float: left; vertical-align: middle;">Powered by</span>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/xxxxxxxx.gif")" alt="Powered by " class="img-responsive "/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 2):

I recently tried to achieve the same thing, position a span vertically and horizontally inside an image of unknown height and width inside a thumbnail button link. This might be helpful for you or others who struggle.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/n62s5pjb/)

```css
.thumbnail:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.centered > span.fa-play-circle-o{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

a.thumbnail:hover .centered span.fa-play-circle-o{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <!-- inline color for visual debugging only -->
    <div class="row" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:pink;">
            <p class="text-center">text above</p>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail btn btn-default">
                <div class="centered">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200" />
                    <span class="fa fa-2x fa-play-circle-o"></span>
                </div>    
            </a>
            <p class="text-center">larger text<br/>below</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

Using **Absolute position**

Using **display:table**

**USING ABSOLUTE POSITION**

DESC: Give parent element {{position:relative}} and child(element to be centered) as

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**USING TABLE BLOCK**

DESC: Give parent element as display:table;width:100% and second parent as display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;

**Note***: {table-row} should have some height greater than its content.

Answer (score 0):

Just use  tag..

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">

            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/xxxxxxxx.gif")" alt="Powered by " class="img-responsive "/>
            <div style="float: left; vertical-align: middle;">Powered by</div>
        </a>
```

---

You can also use span tag as i tried but just put span tag under the img tag and a href text will be under the image..if you have any other question then please let me know..

hope it will work